# Modelling a recursive stock system with non-

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to model a business domain that produces stock that actually has a complex recursive stock system.

1. Stock can be uniquely labeled at the item level, or;
2. Stock can be uniquely labeled at the box level (containing a number of un-identifyable items), or;
3. Stock can be labelled at the pallet level (containing a number of un-identifyable boxes), or;
4. Stock can be labelled uniquely and then contained within levels above, i.e. unique items in a unique box. Or unique items directly placed on a unique pallet.

Here is what I was thinking, however I'm not sure about the "QuantityOfUnidetifyableInners", but I don't know any better way to model a system that may or may not uniquely identify it's entities, so any advice on that woud be appreciated, or if anyone can see an alternative approach to the problem.

```
/// <summary>
/// ValueObject
/// </summary>
public sealed class StockIdentity
{
    private readonly string _serial;

    public StockIdentity(string serial)
    {
        _serial = serial;
    }

    public string Serial { get { return _serial; } }

    //...equals contract
}

/// <summary>
/// Entity
/// </summary>
public sealed class StockItem
{
    public StockIdentity Id { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOfNonIdentifiableInners { get; set; }
    public StockItem[] Identifiable { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to depend heavily on the domain.  Stock is a funny thing.  Not everything will have a serial number.  Most of the issues you have you may be able to solve with some `UnitOfMeasure` / `UnitOfIssue` with a conversion table between them.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the domain and what you're trying to achieve and what your problems are? I can't speak about the validity of your proposed design because I'm not sure how it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea: why do you need this quantity? Is it even necessary in your domain model, or is it just something that belongs in your read model?

If it is, I would assume that the quantity is something you need to verify whether all the items are still there, so i would assume you would call it something like

```
 ItemCount
```

I assume domain experts do not say something like "Hey, for every label we have a quantity of non identifiable inners", but probably something like "later on, we count the items to make sure everything is there".

Domain experts tend to be very - even too much - aware of the things they say when they know their words will be used as a baseline to implement software, so they tend to speak more formal.

The minute you ask a side question, they usually stop caring about their formal language, and then they start speaking their "true" domain language; it happens in a very subtle way, and it is sometimes hard to notice, but that is usually the part where the value is.

YMMV.